# Good practice when accessing a field in a class

Tags: java, software-design

When you have to access a "member variable"/field in a class, is it good practice to access it directly or call the getter and setter? and why?

Comment: Read this, it answers the "Why?" part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see almost only benefits in making your fields private and only provide access through a getter and possibly a setter

- controlled access. If you only want to provide read access, or only write access you can only achieve this by using getters/setters
- if you want to fire `PropertyChangeEvents` for bean properties, you can include this code in your setter. Otherwise all calls which modify this field directly should trigger a change event as well
- I personally find it easier to discover in my IDE who modifies the field. The only direct access to the field is in the class (since it is a private field), and all external changes go through the setter. This allows for faster debugging than having to use a field watchpoint
- subclasses who want to do something extra when the field change can override the setter, call `super.set` and do something extra

The only possible drawback I can think of is that it requires a bit more code to write (for the getters and setters), and a bit more code for accessing the field from outside the class. But with the current IDEs is this a pretty lame excuse

Some extra literature:
[link1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50225/are-javas-public-fields-just-a-tragic-historical-design-flaw-at-this-point), [link2](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/statement-against-public-fields-in-java/)

Answer (score 3):

Call the setter/getter rather than accessing directly. That way any extra required code in the setter/getter will be run.

Answer (score 2):

Getter/ Setter allows for lazy instantiation, which is often a way to go. Additionally, this way you have a controlled access to your variables (both for yourself and as part of any API you may want to expose); ability to hide implementation of initialization etc are also very important.

The biggest benefits of S/G in my opinion is reduced risk of someone modifying it without your control. A small example .. consider that a getter may give you .. a `copy` of the original instead of an original.

Benefits are multiple, when given a choice, choose setter/ getter for the benefits of data encapsulation and more control.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a member of the calling class, access it directly.  Otherwise use the getter/setter methods.

Why? You should not be creating getter/setter methods just so that the calling class can access its own members.  Otherwise you should use the getter/setter methods for the reasons elaborated by others.